AnyLogic: Pedestrian Library, How to define target lines in child agent and reach it from main agent
I have defined a custom block representing both graphically and logically gates in a metro station model, in which I have defined a parameter of type TargetLine. In Main model I have used the agent "gateEntity" and have set the input parameter of the block by assigning a defined Target Line to it, but when the peds are walking through newly defined agent, following error is thrown:
> Exception during discrete event execution:
> root.gateEntity.pedService.?<PedSettings>.pedLevels_xjal[0].pedServices[0].queues[6].queue.goTo_xjal:
> Unreachable target: (120.00, 46.91) on level 'name: levelNew' for
> pedestrian 'id: 1' located at: (359.21, 320.21) on level 'name:
> level'!

levelNew is the level defined in child agent, it seems that I should link the level of main agent to level of child agent but how?
this is my child agent image and how levelNew is set for services:

and this is my Main  agent when my newly defined block is selected:



UPDATE:
the model after adding pedExit in Main:

and gateEntity after adding pedEnter:

but the following error is thrown:
Agent (Agent#1[root.pedExit]:root.pedExit.processBlock.output.output.out->root.gateEntity.pedEnter.processBlock.input.in)can't be in several flowcharts at the time. At least two flowchart blocks are in conflict: root.gateEntity.pedEnter and root.pedExit

I think you need to use pedEnter and pedExit when you are using things that are not in the main layout agent.

@Felipe thanks, I've used a pedExit in Main and a pedEnter in my GateEntity, but following error is thrown: Agent (Agent#1[root.pedExit]:root.pedExit.processBlock.output.output.out->root.gateEntity.pedEnter.processBlock.input.in)can't be in several flowcharts at the time. At least two flowchart blocks are in conflict: root.gateEntity.pedEnter and root.pedExit

you are doing something wrong but i would need to see the flow, update your question with the new model

@Felipe the question was updated, thanks in advance.
